# What is the purpose of coating around heating element in soldering airgun?

Tags: identification

I have disassembled my SMD reworking airgun (to determine the cause of a 5-E error) and in aigun I have found a paper-like coating wrapped around the heating element that totally crumbled to dust and little pieces when I touched it.
[image]

What is the purpose of this coating? Could I use the aigun without it or I will get some problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mica sheets are used as electrical insulators for heatsinks , heater guns and  microwave ovens , [maybe (salvage) from old toasters](https://www.highmica.com/products/flexible-mica-sheet)

[image]

It prevents the body plastic from melting and is rated by thickness.  The heater coil also has high AC voltage on it.

Looks like you cooked it maybe by blocking the intake air or cheap quality inadequate thickness.

Good luck.

Comment: thanks for the answer. BTW the plastic is used just for the handle, the heating element is placed in a steel pipe.

Comment: OK then its for electrical safety

Comment: I estimate the wire  gets to dim red 1000'C but reduced airflow can raise the temp and make it more red and degrade the mica

Comment: I wonder if the gun actually senses voltage induced on the pipe.  5-E error

Comment: Interesting question. This error usually is caused by some disconnected cable that prevents the correct temperature control, but I have checked them and seems all well connected and other than cooked coating I don't see anything wrong. (Also I'm wondering if this thing is toxic, since the thin dust is easy to be inadvertently inhaled).

Comment: Not as toxic as Asbestos or outgassing of super heated epoxy

Comment: it's used to make metallic looking paints so it's considered to be less toxic than lead, (which is no longer used in paint)

Comment: Lead, asbestos, are extremely carcinogenic, less toxic than them isn't particularly encouraging XD. However, regarding the doubt above, I have found that 5-E error has been caused by a faulty thermocouple located in the airgun handle, replacing it and resetting the station, now started to work again although it hasn't any coating anymore and I'm not sure about the risk of using it before put a replacement coating, and I don't know what coating should buy since the one in it was totally cooked and I haven't used it too much so I suppose such mica sheets haven't all good enough heat resistance.

Comment: MSDS says hazardous but non-dangerous.. Meaning don't inhale more than the hazardous limit that causes breathing issues.  Did  you order some samples or get replacement from the factory ?  If the fan failed during heat, it could cause your failures.  You can run exposed to test. or Ohm out

Comment: If you refer to the replaced thermocouple I have found a suitable sample in my spare parts inventory.

Answer (score 2):

That is a heat shield to protect the body from damage.

You need to replace it **before** using the airgun again.